# SendKeys not working on Fraps

Tags: c#, sendkeys

For those not familiar with fraps. Its screen recording program that you can trigger with key shortcuts.

I am using triggering fraps using the SendKeys.SendWait call. I noticed this is not triggering fraps to record any video but if I manually press the key, fraps would being recording. Is there a way to figure out if fraps is doing that is disallowing me from doing this?

I'm able to start the program and navigate its menu, so I'm pretty sure I am using SendKeys correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/

This worked.

This windows API simulated text entry but not keystrokes. This library does keystrokes.