# Powershell script to start FRAPS recording

Tags: c#, powershell

I want to create a script which is starting a FRAPS recording. From everything I read and tried it seems that `SendKeys` is not working with this solution. When I activate the app and then go for pushing the hot key it is not doing anything.

I then found [SendKeys not working on Fraps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3184668/sendkeys-not-working-on-fraps) explaining to do it in a different way simulating real key press. For some reason I am not able to implement it at all.

I have tried to give direct path to the DLL and also to use `gacutil` but the error is still the same. Could you please give me some suggestions where I am doing it wrong?

For the moment the non working part is looking like this:

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('FRAPS movies');
Sleep 1
$Source = @"
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WindowsInput;

namespace CSharpPS
{
    public static class PS
    {
        public static void NewVD()
        {
            InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_LWIN);
        }        
    }
}
"@;

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies InputSimulator.dll
```

and the errors are

```
Add-Type : c:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\0ecf0w0t.0.cs(14) : 'WindowsInput.VirtualKeyCode' does not contain a definition for 'VK_LWIN'
c:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\0ecf0w0t.0.cs(13) :         {
c:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\0ecf0w0t.0.cs(14) : >>>             InputSimulator.SimulateKeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.VK_LWIN);
c:\user\AppData\Local\Temp\0ecf0w0t.0.cs(15) :         }        
At E:\scripts\execution.ps1:30 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssembli ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (c:\Users\user\A...n for 'VK_LWIN':CompilerError) [Add-Type], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SOURCE_CODE_ERROR,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand

Add-Type : Cannot add type. Compilation errors occurred.
At E:\scripts\execution.ps1:30 char:1
+ Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssembli ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Type], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : COMPILER_ERRORS,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddTypeCommand
```